# Show that the vector field always admits a potential function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

Let $r = ||X||$. Let $g$ be a differentiable function of one variable. Now to show that the vector field defined by
$$F(X) = \frac{g'(r)}{r} X$$
in the domain $X \neq 0$ always admits a potential function. What is the potential function?

I learnt that if the domain of the vector field is the whole space or a rectangle or a open ball i.e a connected set than $D_if_j = D_jf_i$ for all indices $i,j$ implies that $F$ has a potential function, where $f_i$'s are the component functions of $F$.
But in this question the domain is punctured at $X=0$ so we can't conclude that $F$ has a potential function by previous statement.

So how can I prove that $F$ admits a potential function in this case.

Comment: Have you tried $\phi(X)=g\left(\|X\|\right)$?

Comment: Yes, this function serves as the potential function of F, but how to determine this function from the given vector field. Means I want to say that without preassuming this function as the potential function can I find this from F?